# How do I remove all underscores (_) in for-each in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, foreach

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/Root">
        <SetShortNames>
            <xsl:for-each select="/Root/SetShortName">
                <SetShortName>
                    **SetShortNameWithNoUnderscoresHere**
                </SetShortName>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </SetShortNames>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to remove all underscores from the value matched in the foreach. How can I accomplish this in XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assumes replace with nothing:)

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate(., "_", "")' />
```

Comment: That did it but your arguments are in the wrong order. Should be <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '_', '')" />

Comment: Damn... been a while since I got my XSLT on!